# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I am sure that my api is successfully connected with `popularGamesURL` `upcomingGamesURL` and `newGamesURL`

when I try to fetch my api then show me error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'popular' of undefined
```

I have tried this way

`gamesAction.js` file:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { popularGamesURL, upcomingGamesURL, newGamesURL } from "../api";

//Action creator

export const loadGames = () => async (dispatch) => {
  //Fetch axios
  const popularData = await axios.get(popularGamesURL());
  const newGamesData = await axios.get(newGamesURL());
  const upcomingData = await axios.get(upcomingGamesURL());

  dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_GAMES",
    paylaod: {
      popular: popularData.data.results,
      upcoming: upcomingData.data.results,
      newGames: newGamesData.data.results,
    },
  });
};
```

`gamesReducer.js` file:

```
const initialState = {
  popular: [],
  newGames: [],
  upcoming: [],
  searched: [],
};

const gamesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_GAMES":
      return {
        ...state,
        popular: action.payload.popular,
        upcoming: action.payload.upcoming,
        newGames: action.payload.newGames,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }
};

export default gamesReducer;
```

I'm tried to find error.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dispatching an action with a wrong property name of `paylaod`(note the **ao** instead of **oa**) in your `gamesAction.js` and you're expecting a property named `payload` in your reducer.

```
  dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_GAMES",
    paylaod: { // <=== this
      popular: popularData.data.results,
      upcoming: upcomingData.data.results,
      newGames: newGamesData.data.results,
    },
  });
```

A simple typo which you should have all the means to debug yourself locally.

Comment: Thank you!  I have try to find around 1 hour ....typeError <: